# Rename file by comparing the filesname in two folder bash/sed

Tags: bash, sed

I was playing with bash i get stucked in one problem .

In first folder i have file list as

```
folder1/first_1.txt
folder1/second_2.txt
folder1/third_3.txt
folder1/फाइल_3.txt
```

In second folder i have file list as

```
folder2/1.txt
folder2/2.txt
folder2/3.txt
```

Now, i need to compare filename from first and second folder and replace the filename of second folder with first folder filename as

```
ouputfolder/fist.text
ouputfolder/second.text
ouputfolder/third.text
ouputfolder/फाइल.text
```

How can it be done using bash/sed ? Any suggestion are appreciated.

Comment: do you also want content to be copied of `folder2` files into `outputFolder`?

Comment: Yeah that will be good i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `find` to find the files in `folder1` and a `while` loop to check existence of the relevant portion of the each filename in filenames of `folder2`. If present, then necessary renaming is done :

```
find folder1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | \
  while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file; do start="${file%%_*}"; end="${file#*_}"; \
   [ -f folder2/"$end" ] && echo mv -i folder2/"$end" folder2/"$start".text; done
```

Satisfied with the change to be made? If Ok, then remove `echo` to let the operation take place:

```
find folder1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | \
   while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file; do start="${file%%_*}"; end="${file#*_}"; \
     [ -f folder2/"$end" ] && mv -i folder2/"$end" folder2/"$start".text; done
```

**Example:**

```
% tree
.
├── folder1
│   ├── first_1.txt
│   ├── second_2.txt
│   └── third_3.txt
└── folder2
    ├── 1.txt
    ├── 2.txt
    └── 3.txt


% find folder1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file; do start="${file%%_*}"; end="${file#*_}"; [ -f folder2/"$end" ] && echo mv -i folder2/"$end" folder2/"$start".text; done
mv -i folder2/2.txt folder2/second.text
mv -i folder2/3.txt folder2/third.text
mv -i folder2/1.txt folder2/first.text

% find folder1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file; do start="${file%%_*}"; end="${file#*_}"; [ -f folder2/"$end" ] && mv -i folder2/"$end" folder2/"$start".text; done 

% tree                                                  
.
├── folder1
│   ├── first_1.txt
│   ├── second_2.txt
│   └── third_3.txt
└── folder2
    ├── first.text
    ├── second.text
    └── third.text
```

Comment: what about unicode character in file name as फाइल.txt ?? I think this script will not work right ??

Comment: @Drudge Working fine for me..if an issue, check your `locale`

Comment: what should be locale ?? I am confused .

Comment: i had also same mate :( . Now i am going to be crazy

Comment: when i use your solution, neither it is working not showing errors. So, i thought it was unicode  problem .

Comment: @heemayl This script succeeds to rename all files, but the filenames containing \n are truncated. See the test in my answer.

Comment: @heemayl ; Errors got generated when this new version is run: mv: cannot move 'folder2/3.txt' to 'folder2/folder1/third.text': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

EDITED in order to be fully functional with all filenames.

**sed** can be used to search and replace strings in files. It is not naturally used for filename.

Give this tested version a try (also checked with shellcheck):

```
#!/bin/bash --
find folder2 -name \*.txt -printf "%f\n" | while read -r folder2fn ; do
  folder1fn=$(find folder1 -name \*_"${folder2fn}" -printf "%f");
  mv folder2/"${folder2fn}" folder2/"${folder1fn%_${folder2fn}}".text
done
```

Build the test folders:

```
mkdir folder1
printf "f1 %s\n" "one" > folder1/first_1.txt
printf "f1 %s\n" "two" > folder1/second_2.txt
printf "f1 %s\n" "three" > folder1/third_3.txt
printf "f1 %s\n" "four" > folder1/"$(printf "\0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\10\11\12\13\14\15\16\17\20\21\22\23\24\25\26\27\30\31\32\33\34\35\36\37\40\42\47\54\77\134\140\177")"_4.txt
mkdir folder2
printf "f2 %s\n" "one" > folder2/1.txt
printf "f2 %s\n" "two" > folder2/2.txt
printf "f2 %s\n" "three" > folder2/3.txt
printf "f2 %s\n" "four" > folder2/4.txt
```

List the test elements:

```
ls -1b folder*/*.txt

folder1/\001\002\003\004\005\006\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\016\017\020\021\022\023\024\025\026\027\030\031\032\033\034\035\036\037\ "',?\\`\177_4.txt
folder1/first_1.txt
folder1/second_2.txt
folder1/third_3.txt
folder2/1.txt
folder2/2.txt
folder2/3.txt
folder2/4.txt
```

Run the script:

```
./newscript.sh
```

Display the new files and check the result:

```
ls -1b folder2/*.text

folder2/\001\002\003\004\005\006\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\016\017\020\021\022\023\024\025\026\027\030\031\032\033\034\035\036\037\ "',?\\`\177.text
folder2/first.text
folder2/second.text
folder2/third.text
```

### Alternative one line version

I found this funny :) 
It has been tested as well and verified with shellcheck.

```
find folder2 -name \*.txt -printf "%f\0" | xargs -0 -I xxxx bash -c '( folder1fn=$(find folder1 -name \*_xxxx -printf "%f") ; mv folder2/xxxx folder2/"${folder1fn%_xxxx}".text )'
```

Comment: DO NOT USE `ls` output for anything. `ls` is a tool for interactively looking at directory metadata. Any attempts at parsing `ls` output with code are broken. Globs are much more simple AND correct: 
                `for file in *.txt`. Read [Parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: True !  I assumed (without writing it) that all filenames only contain [0-9a-zA-Z.] chars, see the question and its filenames examples.

Comment: ok, A second version special chars proof is coming at the end of the day (french alps).

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein: the new version without ls had been provided.

Comment: @Drudge It has been tested ok with a weird filename and the script had been verified with **shellcheck**. Please give this version a try.